# How to use msgs in ros

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi dear
I want to write a program that is tell me how many msgs that one node has published
How can I write this program
I wrot this program but it's not worked

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
int i=0;
  void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
 {
  //ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
      i++;
 }

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      ros::init(argc, argv, "lisiner");
      ros::NodeHandle n;
      ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chater", 1000, chatterCallback);
      ros::Rate timeloop(5);
      while(ros::ok())
      {
          ROS_INFO("%d",i);
          timeloop.sleep();

      }

      return 0;
  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96526/how-to-use-msgs-in-ros/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2013-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to add `ros::spinOnce()` into your while loop.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2013-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-10-31**:
I test this but the node that published, publish 30 msgs but this node count 29 msgs
how can I fix this?

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-10-31**:
Are you sure that you really send 30 messages, which one is left out? (hint: use the seq field in the header and rostopic to track what is going on, display the same data in your program and compare).

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-11-02**:
I have one node that published msgs and in this node in terminal count how many msgs has been published
when 30 msgs published I press ctr+c to shut down the node but my Subscriber node count 29 and when after 50 msgs i press ctr+c the Subscriber node has count 47

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-11-03**:
Did you try to use suggested "seq" field? It's good idea to use it.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-11-05**:
tnx man :)